# Bind event from Iframe to parent window (Cross Browser)

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent

I have an iframe that needs to to scroll the parent to top.
Directly, using parent it is not possible for security reasons.

Is there other way maybe by binding events.
Can you post a sample of how to do it?

(Using jquery in iframe and parent)

Thanks